# Regexp: whitespace in filename Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I've got a regexp that looks for whitespace, hyphens, underscores and %20 in a filename

```
/\s+|-+|_+|%20+/gi
```

If the filename has any hyphens etch then they will be converted to spaces. I'm not worred about the extension

- this-is_my%20file­­­&shywhich-is-an_image

will be changed to

- this is my file which is an image

It works fine but I'm not sure if using the case OR case OR case method is the right way to go. Also the above will not match soft hyphens but I'm not sure how to do that.
 Cheers.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - He probably seeks `%20` but not `00222%`.

Comment: Do you have an example with soft hyphen? Do you also want to convert soft hyphen to space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shorter version like so:

```
/(\s|-|_|%20)+/gi
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on your use case.

If you want to replace all whitespace by a single dash. So `"abc_-def"` becomes `"abc-def"`. In this case your current regular expression will give `"abc--def"` instead.

To ammend this you can move the `+`, like so:

```
"abc-_def".replace(/([\s\-_]|%20)+/gi, "-"); // "abc-def"
```

Answer (score 1):

We're going to need some context here. If you just want to see whether the filename contains one of them, use this:

```
/\s|\-|%20/
```

That'll return true if the filename contains any of them, or false if it doesn't.

If you want anything more than that, you're going to need to tell us what you need it for. Do you want to replace them with something else? Do you want to return true if all of them are present?

EDIT: You've edited your question, thanks. The way you're doing it is fine, yes.

Comment: You don't have to escape `-`... just sayin'.

Comment: It doesn't hurt, though, and it prevents possible confusion at a later date.

Comment: You only have to escape the `-` if you're within `[` `]`, like `[a-z\-]` (a to z and dash)

Comment: I know. It's a literal hyphen when outside of a character class. However, see my above comment.